# How do I restrict permissions appropriately for Team System Web Access?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

We're using Team Foundation Server 2008 and we have a few users that do not have CALs but we'd like them to be able to enter their own work items and view them. We have the Team System Web Access installed and once the users are in the TFS Valid Users group they can get to the site. I've seen mention of a particular view at http://server:8090/wiwa that would restrict access to the appropriate level for the users that don't have CALs, but they get a page not found error if they try that.

I'm also trying to figure out what permissions I'll need to set on the TFS side to allow them create/edit their work items. In short, we are trying to comply with the licensing restrictions but doin so doesn't seem at all straight forward. If anyone has already been through this and could point me in the right direction, I'd very much appreciate it.

In the interim, I'll continue wading through the docs to see if there's some clear guidance hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WIWA is a separate web application that has only recently been packaged into the TSWA installer.  Make sure you have the latest one.  That's [2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=3ecd00ba-972b-4120-a8d5-3d38311893de) + [this security patch](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/02/02/important-team-system-web-access-update.aspx).

Note that the security patch may [break attachment downloads in WIWA](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/tfswebaccess/thread/e54df26e-88de-4ab4-9c5a-ae47f75373f4).  I'm not sure if the fix for the latter issue is available yet.

Once WIWA is working, anyone who uses that URL will only be able to create & edit their own work items.  All you have to do is keep non-CAL users from accessing the main TSWA site.